# Can I use $C^1$MVT in this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Recently I did a problem about if f if is differentiable on $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and if $(Df)_p=0$ for all $p$, then f is constant. I used $C^1$MVT there. Now, what if $(D^2f)_p=0$? Can I use $C^1$MVT here?

Comment: You mean $(Df)_p=0$ for all $p$? So $C^1$, eh?

Comment: No, that's clear. I'm interested what happens when $(D^2f)_p = 0$ for all p. And by $C^1$MVT I mean a generalization of the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Again, it's *crucial* to put *for all $p$* in your original statement. For your second version, apply the $C^1$ MVT to the mapping $G\colon U\to L(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m)$ ($L(V,W)$ standing for the vector space of linear maps from $V$ to $W$), given by $G(p) = (Df)_p$.

Comment: @TedShifrin : Sorry, I didn't read well your comment. Yes, the crucial is to put for all $p$, I somehow droped it. But how to begin with $C^1$MVT here for second derivative?